# How to define @Parameter annotation in Maven POM

Tags: maven, parameters, mojo

I wrote a Mojo Plugin and set two @Parameter (import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Parameter;)

I want to configure the Parameters in the POM of the project where I want to use this plugin.

No matter where everytime I get an error message.

The part of the POM:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.tup.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>versionsextra</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>path</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <path>${basedir}/src/main/resources/configsys/dev/etc/deploy_env</path>

                    </configuration>

                </execution>
            </executions>
```

So one of the Parameter is called path:

```
 @Parameter()

private String path;
```

Comment: what error message are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

ok, I got it.

I have to declare it like this:

```
@Mojo(name="devversion")

public class ParameterMojo extends AbstractMojo {

@Parameter()
private String path;

@Parameter()
private String pathsave;

...
```

And in POM:

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>com.tup.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>versionsextra</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>testen</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>devversion</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <path>${basedir}/src/main/resources/configsys/dev/etc/deploy_env</path>
                        <pathsave>${basedir}/src/main/resources/configsys/dev/etc/test.txt</pathsave>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>                        
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: because this solution adds annotations to the code, the artifact `maven-plugin-annotations` must also be added to the POM